# Whats wrong with my sql code

Tags: php, html, mysql

It seems when i try my code of

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO MyGuests (username, password, email, name) VALUES("'.$uname.'", "'.$pword.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$name.'")';
```

I get the error of

> ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO MyGuests (username, password, email, name) VALUES("anything", "anything", "anything", "anything").

Are there any immidiate red flags I would love some help!

Here's all of my code

```
    <?php
get_header(); 
?>
    <?php
include('config.php');
mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Nex']);
    $pword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Pex']); 
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Naex']); 
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Eex']); 


$sql = 'INSERT INTO MyGuests (username, password, email, name) VALUES('".$uname."', '".$pword."', '".$email."', '".$name."')'; 
echo'account created.';
echo"$uname";
echo"$pword";
echo"$name";
echo"$email";
} else { ?>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">

label {
    width:180px;
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}

input, label {
    float:left;
}
</style>
<h1> Create A Account </h1>
<form method="post" action="">
<label for="Nex">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="Nex" </input>
<label for="Pex">Password:</label>
<input type="text" name="Pex" </input>
<label for="Eex">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="Eex" </input>
<label for="Eex">Name of scout:</label>
<input type="text" name="Naex" </input>
<input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit" />  
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Along with my config.php (with the login stuff hidden lol)

```
<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'dbserver');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'uname');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pword');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'uname');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
<?php
//Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.
$hostname = "dbserver";
$username = "uname";
$dbname = "uname";

//These variable values need to be changed by you before deploying
$password = "pword";
$usertable = "uname";
$yourfield = "MyGuests";

//Connecting to your database
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to
connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//Fetching from your database table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row["$yourfield"];
        echo "Name $name<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This case may have multiple problems.  Please edit your question to offer more details, specifically more php code, and the relevant table structure and potentially a row or two.  All answers, without more details from you, will be working on guesses/assumptions.

Comment: How is it possible for this very broad question with minimal detail and a horrible title has 3 upvotes?!  Nearly unsalvable.

Comment: Modify the PHP code to retrieve the error message returned from MySQL. MySQL could be returning an error for a variety of reasons: specified column names don't exist in MyGuests table, the case of the table identifier may not match (case sensitive), sqlmode includes ANSI_QUOTES disallows double quotes around string literals, unique key violation, foreign key constraint violation, a NOT NULL constraint violation, insufficient privileges, fired trigger throws error, no default database specified. There's a whole slew of possibilities. With the information provided, we can only speculate.

Comment: I added alot more information (all of it) could you re-look it over ive been really stumped

Comment: The code assigns a string to a variable that happens to be named `$sql`. But we don't see any code that submits the SQL text to the database to be executed. After the assignment, the code does an "echo 'account created.'".

Comment: Your code as shown is mixing libraries - you can't use `mysql_` and `mysqli_` together, nor should you be using the former to begin with (it's been deprecated for quite a while now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade to add this code which fixed it for anybody who is asking this not broad question

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO MyGuests(username,password,name,email)
                VALUES('$uname','$pword','$name','$email')");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a quote problem
Try this one:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (username, password, email, name) VALUES('".$uname."', '".$pword."', '".$email."', '".$name."')";
```

Comment: The stop starts are unnecessary - but this method is insecure and archaic, so see about PDO and parametrised queries

Comment: it still comes up with the same error i dont know what wrong with it.